# Find the difference App layout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, screen-size, custom-view

I want to create a find the difference in 2 images kind of app in Native Android.

I have done this using a Custom view with 2 images side by side and finding the touch positions (X, Y) of the image and it kind of works. But as soon as I try it on a different device the (X, Y) changes.

On one device the bitmap is `(600 x 500)` and the other it is `(800 x 700)`. What can I do to get the aspect ratio same which is `6:5` on all devices?
Is there any alternate way to do this kind of App?

**This is a part of my XML layout.**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<gamesforkids.coloring.games.multipleclickableex.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/signature_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/scene_2"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ring"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ring"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**This is my java onTouch code.**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.signature_canvas:

            x0 = event.getX();
            y0 = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    CanvasView.startTouch(x0, y0);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    CanvasView.moveTouch(x0, y0);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    CanvasView.upTouch();

                    Toast.makeText(this, "X_Value_" + x0 + "_Y_Value_" + y0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (x0 > MyConstant.x0_min && x0 < MyConstant.x0_max && y0 > MyConstant.y0_min && y0 < MyConstant.y0_max)

                    {

                        iv.setX(((MyConstant.x0_max+MyConstant.x0_min)/2));
                        iv.setY(((MyConstant.y0_max+MyConstant.y0_min)/2));
                        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        iv1.setX(((MyConstant.x0_max+MyConstant.x0_min)/2));
                        iv1.setY(((MyConstant.y0_max+MyConstant.y0_min)/2));
                        iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                    if (x0 > MyConstant.x0_min1 && x0 < MyConstant.x0_max1 && y0 > MyConstant.y0_min1 && y0 < MyConstant.y0_max1)

                    {

                        iv_a.setX(((MyConstant.x0_max1+MyConstant.x0_min1)/2));
                        iv_a.setY(((MyConstant.y0_max1+MyConstant.y0_min1)/2));
                        iv_a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        iv_a1.setX(((MyConstant.x0_max1+MyConstant.x0_min1)/2));
                        iv_a1.setY(((MyConstant.y0_max1+MyConstant.y0_min1)/2));
                        iv_a1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    break;
            }

            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

[Link of the screenshot of large device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11U53.png) 
  and [Link of the screenshot of normal device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIuyX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate offsets that depend on the current device.
There are two cases:

1. If the device height is more than (the height of image 1 + the height of image 2): you have to put your images in the center and you will have unused spaces in the top and in the bottom.
2. If the device width is more than (the width of images): you have to put your images in the center and you will have unused spaces in the left and in the right.

[image]